# C# TabControl change headers bar backcolor

Tags: c#, tabcontrol, backcolor

I figured out, with the help of a post in this website, how to redraw each item in a TabControl, which gave me a very satisfying result.

There is just one thing i need to change, and i can't figure out where exactly to look.. The background color of the headers bar.

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYHhb.png)

Does anyone know how to change that ?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: `TabControl1.BackColor = Color.Whatever`? Don't know, just a suggestion.

Comment: There is no BackColor property ^^

Comment: According to MSDN there is: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4sc610z(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: But how to use it ? I can't get access of it by base. or this.

Comment: You cannot even access it via code? Though I'm not sure changing it would do anything.

Comment: It did not change anything, i just override the OnBackgroundPaint and re-drawed the whole control ^^

Comment: @HaitamZanid if that solved the problem then answer your own question with your solution and select it as the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the delay.
I got it working by adding

```
this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint,true);
```

So that i control the OnBackgroundPaint.
Then i override the method to draw the TabControl myself ^^